# Xcode 6.4 Bug? Source code text disappears. OSX Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Is it just me, or does this happen to anyone else? Occasionally if I am coding inside of a huge class, the source code text begins to chop it's way out to a white screen as I scroll.[image] However, when I vigorously scroll to the top, then back down again. The source code re-appears again.
[image]

What could be the issue? Is there a work around? This issue is so annoying!

Comment: I have the same problem too

Comment: I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to communicate this issue to Apple in a bug report. I suppose super detailed information is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences->General tab and uncheck "Show live issues" under Issues. Notice that this is a work around to be able to continue working with Xcode, at least until they issue an official fix. This glitch seems to be noticeable when you have lots of lines of code (1000+).

After this, the glitch will still be happening but not while coding but during building phase. Not perfect but at least you will be able to continue working.